# std::sort with struct containing Eigen datatype causes segfault

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I have the following issue when compiling in release mode
using `MSVC 19.31.31106.2` (and C++17, as far as I understand the eigen page, alignment should be not an issue anymore) that I get a `segfault` from within of `std::sort`.
The official `Eigen 3.4` release is used.

The following compiler flags are set:

```
/errorReport:prompt /WX /Zc:forScope /GR /arch:AVX2 /Gd /MD /std:c++17 /GS /W4 /wd"4389" /wd"4996" /wd"4244" /wd"4324" /wd"4127" /Zc:wchar_t  /EHsc /nologo /Gm- /O2 /Ob2 /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"
```

So I have the following struct:

```c
struct MyStruct
{
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> mVecA{}; 
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> mVecB{};  
    bool mA = true;
    uint64_t mB = 0;
};
```

Then after filling a vector `std::vector<MyStruct> myVec;` with some data the call to

```c
std::sort(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), [](const MyStruct& lhs, const MyStruct& rhs) { return lhs.mB < rhs.mB; });
```

causes a segfault (whereas using `std::stable_sort` causes no issue) it seems to be thrown from inside of `std::move`. In debug mode this does not happen.
Further when changing the order of `MyStruct` to

```c
struct MyStruct
{
    bool mA = true;
    uint64_t mB = 0;
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> mVecA{}; 
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> mVecB{};  
};
```

the segfault does not appear anymore at all.
I don't really understand why this order would be an issue? Shouldn't it also be preferable to avoid unecessary padding within the struct?

Another thing that could fix it would be to explicitly defie alignment for the eigen matrices:

```c
struct MyStruct
{
    alignas(32) Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> mVecA{}; 
    alignas(32) Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> mVecB{};  
    bool mA = true;
    uint64_t mB = 0;
};
```

Here is a minimal example (AVX2 is enabled in the CMake and Eigen needs to be included): Here is an godbolt example: https://godbolt.org/z/odned4axW. (It only works when `/MD` is not added to the flags, otherwise it will not run at all.. which is different from the behaviour on my local machine, where it can still run with `/MD` but causes an exception in the `move` constructor)

```c
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/StdVector>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <iostream> 

int main()
{
    struct MyStruct
    {
        MyStruct() = default;
        MyStruct(const Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>& vecA, const Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>& vecB, uint64_t value, bool boo) : mVecA(vecA), mVecB(vecB), mValue(value), mBool(boo) {}

        alignas(32) Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> mVecA{};
        alignas(32) Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> mVecB{};
        uint64_t mValue = 0;
        bool mBool = true;
    };

    std::vector<MyStruct> mSorted;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        mSorted.emplace_back(Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>::Random(), Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>::Random(), static_cast<uint64_t>(rand()), true);

    std::sort(mSorted.begin(), mSorted.end(), [](const MyStruct& lhs, const MyStruct& rhs) { return lhs.mValue < rhs.mValue; });

    std::cout << mSorted[0].mValue << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Super test" << std::endl;
}
```

The error occurs in `PlainObjectBase.h` line 496 (move constructor of `PlainObjectBase`) traced from (`std::sort` -> `std::_Sort_unchecked` -> `std::_Partition_by_median_guess_unchecked` -> `std::iter_swap` -> `std::swap`).

Comment: smells like UB. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Usually on such cases the defect is in what you address most briefly like "filling with some data".

Comment: Your question is closed, but it is super interesting! Add a minimal example. Take what you have and scale everything you can back until it doesn't break anymore. Then add that, and it will be very cool to figure out what is going on. At that point, we can REOPEN it!!!!

Comment: I added a small example, if `alignas(32)` is removed the crash happens otherwise it runs fine for me.

Comment: Appears to work with latest clang/gcc (and latest Eigen): https://godbolt.org/z/61oaevvGE Can you be more specific what compiler (version) and what Eigen version you are using? Also show all compile flags.

Comment: @chtz I added the versions for compiler (MSVC 19.31.31106.2) and Eigen 3.4
Also I supplied the compiler options for MSVC compiling.

Comment: Removing the `/MD` parameter makes it work: https://godbolt.org/z/s3KxzEsGa (No idea/didn't look up what that does).

Comment: @chtz `MD` does dynamic runtime linkage. `/MT` links runtime statically. It is not a good idea to mix libraries with different runtime linkage. For instance, one could pass an allocated object to another unit that uses a different runtime. Upon destruction the other allocator might deallocate a memory address which it does not have an access to (hence Segmentation Fault)

Comment: how about you post a call stack when the segfault happens?

Comment: I added the call stack to the description (move constructor of eigen object fails within `std::swap`).

Comment: Your godbolt example seems broken in the first place. The program crashes even with uncommented code https://godbolt.org/z/M985GrhE7

Comment: I updated it, it runs now without `/MD` and gives output for me. But with `/MD` i cannot get it to run at all (this behaviour seems different from my local machine)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue locally with the provided compiler flags and the example code at the bottom of the post (although with cl.exe 19.32 and 19.29). Is this really the code that is crashing for you? Also, no idea why the godbolt code with `/MD` does not run: The returned error code 3221225781 is 0xC0000135 in hex, meaning `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`. Apparently, a necessary library is not installed there?

Comment: I know the eigen docs specifically says otherwise...but have you tried the steps here to align the vector allocator: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html?